# how to remove the double quotes in output when i use echo command with "< >" (these charaters) in the string?

Tags: string, batch-file, echo

I wish to create a required no. of html divisions each with a different id (a series).

but when I write  in a loop

```
echo "<div id=%prefix%%i%> %innerHTML% </div>" >> file.txt
```

It should be like

```
  <div id=a1> x </div>
  <div id=a2> x </div>
  <div id=a3> x </div>
```

but it comes out to be

```
  "<div id=a1> x </div>"
  "<div id=a2> x </div>"
  "<div id=a3> x </div>"
```

I have tried omitting the double quotes "" but then it throws an error due to the use of '>' (used to write in a file)

help me with this

Comment: `echo ^<escape them^>`

Comment: The real solution is to not write batch files, especially if you need to create HTML documents.

Comment: You may use `set /P` instead of `echo` this way: `set /P "=< any chars >" >> file.txt < nul` followed by `echo/>> file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo ^<escape them^>
```

this works absolutely fine.

```
echo ^<div id=%prefix%%i%^> %innerHTML% ^</div^> >> file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

An example as per Aacini's comment:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "innerHTML=x"
Set "prefix=a"
(For /L %%A In (1 1 3) Do Set /P "=<div id=%prefix%%%A> %innerHTML% </div>"<Nul&Echo=)>"file.txt"
Pause
```